# How do I expose a C# XLL method to be called from VBA?

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have looked at similar answers on here but nothing quite answers my question.

I have a C# XLL that contains a UDF (powered by ExcelDNA) and some helper classes and methods - one of which is this one:

```csharp
namespace Data_Tool
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class DataCache
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, DataCache> calcs = new Dictionary<string, DataCache> { };
        
        string filepath;
        object[,] data;

        // Class constructor
        public DataCache(string filepath)
        {
            this.filepath = filepath;
            this.data = new object[,] { };
        }
        
        public static void RemoveCache(string filename)
        { // This allows an external entity to call and remove cached data for a particular file
            if (calcs.ContainsKey(filename)) calcs.Remove(filename);
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is use an event handler in Excel VBA (BeforeClose event) to trigger that last method above (RemoveCache) - the purpose is to remove cached items from the 'calcs' Dictionary when the file gets closed.
My VBA code attempts to map the XLL function like so, but I always get an entry-point-not-found error when trying to execute:

```vba
#If Win64 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub RemoveCache Lib "DataTool-AddIn64.xll" (filename As String)
#Else
    Declare PtrSafe Sub RemoveCache Lib "DataTool-AddIn.xll" (filename As String)
#End If

Public Sub test()
    RemoveCache ThisWorkbook.FullName
End Sub
```

You will see that in my C# naiveté, I have tried to use ComVisible to expose the RemoveCache method to COM - but clearly this is incorrect. I am not quite sure how to change my code to make RemoveCache callable from VBA.

Comment: Add the C# DLL as a COM reference

Comment: For architectural reasons of how the workbooks are built, that isn't a practical solution, but definitely works in a test setting. The reason is that users create these macro-enabled workbooks themselves, from the add-in, but not everyone who needs to view the files (e.g. for checking) will have the add-in installed i.e. they will have horrible VBA errors if a reference is defined in the file but missing on their machine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly hacky solution - as I am already using ExcelDNA to generate some UDFs in this same XLL anyway, I have just made a void function called RemoveCache that does the same actions - or indeed just calls the method in C# for me. This allows me to call the function in VBA using Application.Run:

```vba
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next ' Set to skip if the DataTool add-in is not present
    Application.Run "RemoveCache", ThisWorkbook.FullName
End Sub
```

Then my UDF code in C# is:

```csharp
[ExcelFunction(Description = "Erase cache item", IsMacroType = true)]
public static void RemoveCache(string filename)
{
    DataCache.RemoveCacheItem(filename);
}
```

Where **RemoveCacheItem** is my renamed method in the DataCache class from my original question.

Are there any pitfalls with using this approach, as it is quite simple so I like it?